# Where to put logic for auto-login and creating members

Tags: umbraco7

Im new to Umbraco development, but im plenty familiar with ASP.Net & MVC etc.  So Im getting to grips with the object model and terminology used, but Im not sure where to start.  I need to use windows authentication on my Umbraco site, which will be for internal use only.

What I envision: 
- When a domain user hits any area of the website, grab the user identity  
- Lookup to see if matching user(or member) exists and if not create it 
- Login this user to Umbraco 
- By default all new visitors, if their user identity doesnt match a current member, then create that member and log them in.

Sounds like I need to create my own controller that overrides the base controller (RenderMvcController ?) and check the user identity on each and every request?  Maybe do this by overriding the Index action method?  Or could I do this with a macro - or as ive seen mentioned, are macros loosing favor with the new version of Umbraco?

Also, Im not sure how to deal with members vs users?  As I understand it, members are who have access to the front part of the website, whereas users are those that have access to the back office area and can create/manage content.
Are all users also members?
There will be some that I want to give access to create/manage content, so when Im auto-creating users, its actually members that  I need to create, not users?

[ update ] 
Actually, I think I will need to create my own membership provider if I want every request routed through the check for a valid domain user? In my research, I keep coming across this example  http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/2012/07/combined-authentication-with-umbraco/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have overridden the default `RenderMvcController` in numerous projects with success, you could of course use the built in Umbraco auth to redirect to an authentication page for users that do not have a valid Umbraco Auth token and set it only only on that page based on their windows identity.

RE: Are users also members?

No. Users & Members are entirely independent of one another; users being back office users & members being front end users. You will need to create 2 accounts.

Comment: Can you point me at an example or somewhere in the docs that mention this first part (redirect to an auth page) ?  Thanks!  By the way, would something like this work ?  http://24days.in/umbraco/2012/creating-a-login-form-with-umbraco-mvc-surfacecontroller/  The only difference would be that I dont actually want a form, just a controller to handle the creating of the member records and then redirecting to the default page (or the url they were requesting)

Comment: Or something like this possibly https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/6a9a1d1547e7a0508f6bed74c49ee2fd64bcf775/src/Umbraco.Web/Controllers/UmbLoginController.cs

Comment: The redirection can be handled entirely by umbraco using the 'Public Access'- right click the top level page to secure, choose 'Public Access' and select the role(s) you wish to allow access to the page & select your login page. Unauthenticated users will be redirected to the login page by Umbraco. Replicating the 24days.in post should work by replacing the post action with the get and verifying the request yourself before setting the FormsAuthentication cookie...